# Is there a way to not @property then @synthesize?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I hate doing following

```
//in file.h    
@property (strong) NSString *reuseIdentifier;
//in file.m
@synthesize reuseIdentifier = _reuseIdentifier;
```

This feels so redundant. I get the distinction of concepts between property in which is named "reuseIdentifier" and memory block that's named "_reuseIdentifier" but why can't the xcode IDE do the work by itself?

I feel like I am doing chores.

Comment: Xcode (i.e Objective-C compiler) does this work by itself

Comment: @AndreyChernukha so r u saying in xcode I don't need to /@synthesize? Oh dang... then I wonder why all these tutorials online using xcode make me do /@synthesize :(

Comment: you don't need to do this. the tutorials you're talking about must be outdated I think

Comment: It was added to Xcode as "Implicit Synthesized Properties". If you try to switch it off and don't have either synthetize or backing up instance variable you should get error.

Answer (score 4):

It's not been necessary to explicitly implement or synthesize Objective-C properties since Xcode 4.4 in 2012. See the [**Xcode 4.4** section of the archived "What's New in Xcode" documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode-Archive/Articles/xcode_4_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016147-SW11):

> Objective-C `@properties` are synthesized by default when not explicitly implemented.